# Deleted usmt.ppkg, nothing works anymore (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10

I have a computer with very little storage space (28GB).

I wanted to clear some space and I deleted the file usmt.ppkg (from C:\Recovery\Customizations).

After restarting the computer, I found out that I had no more mouse pointer, no more sound, and that the USB ports weren't working anymore.

I was able to recover my mouse pointer by updating the driver in Device Manager, but it doesn't work for the other issues.

I tried resetting the computer, but it doesn't work either (which I guess isn't surprising, since I messed with the Recovery folder...).

Anybody here knows how to fix this ?

Getting all the devices to work again would be great, but I would settle for being able to reset the computer.

Attached is a screenshot of my Device Manager.

My computer is an ASUS E200HA.

Windows 10 version 1607 (OS Build 14393.2214).

[image: DeviceManager]

Comment: Wasn't this file locked by the system? Usually you can open the disk cleanup tool which removes files unneeded, it is a lot safer.

Comment: This package "provisioning package (.ppkg)", stores updates, and applications installed and even used by Windows system since a factory installation. So when you press the recovery button you get those updates and apps. reinstalled. The fsutil.exe is usually used for this file.

Comment: It is probably trying to do Windows Update (V1607 is out of support). 28 GB is usually not enough space for Feature Updates so you need a larger disk drive for your computer

Comment: @ImNotAlone I did not realize you were translating from French, all the Device Manager lines are in English. Anyways the DISM Log file can be found here "__C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log__" You may also want to run SFC /SCANNOW to make sure all files are not damaged and present.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get to Command Prompt, type or paste this command:

```
DISM /Apply-CustomDataImage /CustomDataImage:C:\Recovery\Customizations\USMT.ppkg /ImagePath:C:\ /SingleInstance
```

where `C` is the drive letter of the Windows partition.
**Warning**:  Do not put quotes with the `/ImagePath:C:\` option.

Please see this page: 
[Compact OS, single-instancing, and image optimization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/compact-os?redirectedfrom=MSDN) at docs.microsoft.com

under "**Single-instancing of provisioning packages**"

Please let us, everyone, know if this helps. I have seen it help only one other person before, and others it did not.

Comment: Just tried this command and got an error (code 87).
It basically says (I'm translating from French) that an error occurred, asks me to check the command arguments, and tells me to refer to the dism.log file for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I create a bootable USB and re-installed Windows from there. It worked, problem solved. Thanks for your answers !

Is there anything I should do to mark this question as "SOLVED" ?

Comment: You can't really mark a question as **solved**, but what you can do is to accept an answer that you think solved your problem or the one that answered your question.  You can do that by clicking the gray check mark.  For more info, you can look at the [Help Center related to accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Clean installing windows isn't a solution, it's just clean installing Windows - a Repair Install would have been more efficient