# How to Remove the C:\Recovery\ Folder in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, disk-space, partition-recovery

I am using Windows 10 Home (currently, ver 1909).

I would like to remove the `C:\Recovery\` folder, which takes 3.61GB on my C: partition.

From what I read on the internet, the `C:\Recovery\` folder is used by WinRE,
and since I already use a 3rd party program for creating System Images, then I don't need WinRE..

How can I safely disable WinRE and delete the `C:\Recovery\` folder?

**2 Imoprtant Notes:**
The first:
My `C:\Recovery\` folder does not contain a `winre.wim` file, like what some users suggested in the comments here.
Instead, it contains a 3.61GB file named `USMT.ppkg`.
Its full path is `C:\Recovery\Customizations\USMT.ppkg`

The second:
The current state of WinRE on my Windows10 is Disabled,
as checked via the `reagentc /info` command.

Comment: This is an indication that your system partition and WinRE partition is one in the same.  If you care about the ability to boot into a recovery environment you won't be able to delete the folder.  Microsoft recommends having a WinRE partition.

Comment: Thank you Ramhound. As written above, I do not need MS's recovery environment. I use a 3rd party software which does a great job, and would really like to delete the C:\Recovery\ folder to free up 3.61GB..

Comment: There are many reasons you would need Advanced Startup.  You really shouldn't delete it.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is boot into a live Linux environment and delete it from there. I would suggest [this article](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) to help you.

**Do this first**

Before deleting the folder you need to disable WinRE. To do that open the start menu and type cmd. Right click and hit `Run as Administrator`.

Next type `reagentc /disable` This will diable WinRE.

See [this article](https://winaero.com/enable-or-disable-windows-recovery-environment-in-windows-10/) for more info.

After you do that use the built in ubuntu file manager to mount your C: drive and delete the foler.

Comment: Hi bobsfriend. I understand the part of deleting the folder from outside Windows, so the folder will not be locked/protected in some way, but isn't there some settings that I have to change inside Windows, before deleting the folder? So windows will not scream about a missing file/folder, or worse, give a blue screen..

Comment: @spaceman - [Yes](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/4848-recovery-folder-c.html) which is the reason my recommendation would be just to leave it alone.

Comment: Ramhound:  That person (in the thread you gave) deleted the folder without first disabling WinRE, in Windows.. So I hope that someone here knows how to first disable WinRE, so deleting the folder will not cause any problems afterwards..

Comment: @spaceman I have added some instructions based on an article that I found. I don't use  Windows so I hope it works

Comment: Thank you very much bobsfriend. I will read the articles in the links, then create a System Image using my 3rd party program, then try it. Will reply back here with the results.

Comment: Disabling WinRE will move the file `winre.wim` to the folder
`C:\Windows\System32\Recovery`. You won't economize as much as you think.

Comment: Hi all. Please see the update I added to the question. It seems that I never had a `winre.wim` file in `C:\Recovery`, probably because originally my laptop came with a Recovery partition, which I deleted using DISKPART. So `winre.wim` is not the problem, instead, `C:\Recovery\Customizations` contains a 3.61GB file called `USMT.ppkg`. Any info on what can be done to get rid of this folder (or file) will be great.

Comment: @spaceman After reading [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/SCCM/comments/3t21dd/coworker_accidently_deleted_usmt_package/) It seems like it is safe to delete as they didn't mention anything about not booting, blue screens, etc. you can still follow the same thing as I put in my answer to delete it.

Comment: I would also see [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1517095/deleted-usmt-ppkg-nothing-works-anymore-windows-10) that says it trashed their computer.

Comment: Yes. Searching Google for `"windows 10" "USMT.ppkg"`, gives endless results of people who deleted it, and now have problems with Windows. I wonder what is the contents of this file, and If there's a good way to delete it, without causing problems afterwards. I would really like to get rid of this 3.61GB file..